# Unable to connect to Mongodb on docker on windows

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have mongodb docker instance running in my windows machine.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS          PORTS                                            NAMES
8fa2abece6fc   mongo:latest               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 42 seconds   27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27017->27107/tcp              mongo-container
```

I use these two commands

```
docker network create --atachable -d overlay springBankNet 

docker run -it -d --name mongo-container -p 27017:27107 --network springBankNet --restart always -v mongodb_data_container:/data/db mongo:latest
```

I can successfully go inside the container using

```
 docker exec -it mongo-container bash
```

But when I try to connect it with Studio 3T or MongoDB Compass. I face issues.

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [localhost:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketReadException): Prematurely reached end of stream

Details:
Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
```

When I connected with Spring Project, After running mvn clean install, I am getting the following error, although mongodb docker instance is running in my machine.

```
2022-07-20 19:40:22.636  INFO 5768 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Windows", "name": "Windows 10", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "10.0"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/15.0.2+7-27"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@186d8a71]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
2022-07-20 19:40:22.718  INFO 5768 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:713) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:571) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:410) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:337) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:45) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Note: I haven't connected it using any username or password. It is just a general connection.

Please help.

And finally, what is the difference between `docker rm <name>` command and `docker container rm <name>` command?

Comment: Any firewall in the way? Also, have you checked your ports on the windows machine to confirm that port 27107 is listening?

Comment: Recently installed Kaspersky, So need to check about the firewalls. And at first I have installed Mongodb in my local, but I uninstalled it before running docker  So it should be free.

Answer (score 1):

> And finally, what is the difference between `docker rm <name>` command and `docker container rm <name>` command?

Nothing; they're the same thing, just a different way to do it.